# wordpress nav displaying mobile on desktop

Tags: wordpress

i am having an issue with nav bar. I have not made any updates to the code after I used the theme. It was working perfectly but now it just looks crazy.

Here is the url. http://digitalcoachsolutions.com/

any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. I deleted the menu and this the random one it generated.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS to your website:

```
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#undefined-sticky-wrapper {
    height: auto;
}
```